# CSS allign in one line 4 fields

Tags: css

I have i need help to align the fields in one row. For now each field creates new line. The css code is below.

```
.STSearch [type="text"],

.STSearch select {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.STSearch [type="checkbox"],
.STSearch [type="radio"] {
    margin: 5px 0;

}

.STSearch [type="checkbox"] + label,
.STSearch [type="radio"] + label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.STSearch .stslide .STSearchLabel  label:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #666;
    margin-bottom: .2em;
    margin-left: .2em;
    vertical-align: left;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

For now the outcome is each field to be in new line

Thank you for your help

Comment: you forgot to add the HTML code...

Comment: All the text boxes are 100% wide, is that right?

Comment: Yes. I did fixed it by creating new classes in other files.Thnx